# MemoryError in Python with indefinitely ending code

Tags: python, memory, hash, monitor

I am trying to write a Python program that runs indefinitely in the background (till the user stops it) and detects any changes to a webpage. So I hash the contents of the page and compare to previous hash, if the values change then I know that the page has changed. Here is my code:

```
import requests
import threading
import hashlib
from urllib.request import urlopen


URL = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/live/football/55864099'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36'}
current_hash = 'Initial'

def monitor():
    threading.Timer(5, monitor).start() #The number in the Timer() bracket represents the scheduling interval in seconds
    response = urlopen(URL).read()
    new_hash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest()
    global current_hash
    if(current_hash == new_hash):
        print('same')
    else:
        print('different')
        current_hash = new_hash

monitor()
```

However, after running for a few minutes, I get this error in console:

```
MemoryError
```

But sometimes the program continues after a short delay. Is there anyway to clear the memory as I go along to prevent this error from occurring?

Comment: Are you seriously bombarding a server with 10 requests per second‽ If a request takes longer than 100ms to complete, you’re starting to run more and more threads in parallel…!

Comment: I realised that was a bit extreme so I have set the interval to 5 seconds instead (and changed the initial question to reflect that) and now I haven't had the error pop up but I feel like if I ran it for a few hours at a time, it might pop up so would still like to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

From python docs, if something has a close, you should call close or just suffer out of MemoryErrors, or whatever resources needs clean up. You really can only skip calling close after you've read the source behind a close() method and determined it doesn't do anything.

```
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org/') as f:
...     print(f.read(300))
```

You should also follow an exponential backoff, fix interval polling just keeps your CPU warm and shortens its lifespan, one library to do that: https://pypi.org/project/backoff/